# Prove that the triangle is isosceles, based on the intersection of two line segments connecting vertices to sides

Tags: geometry, triangles

[image]

Given $AB=AC$ and $DE=DF$, prove $DB=DC$

I have no idea how to solve it using elementary way, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume by contradiction $DB >DC$ (The case $DC>DB$ is identical).

Then in triangle $DBC$ we have $\angle DCB > \angle DBC$. Therefore

$\angle FCA > \angle EBA$. As $\angle EAB =\angle FAC$ we get 
$$\angle AFC < \angle BEA \,.$$

Now, comparing triangles $ABE$ and $AFC$ since $\angle EAB =\angle FAC, AB=AC$ and $\angle AFC < \angle BEA$ you get $BE <FC$ (use for example sin law). But this contradicts $BD> DC$.

Comment: I was trying this approach as well but when using the sine law we need to consider the case where angle $BEC$ or $BFC$ is greater than 90 degrees which does not seem to be considered here.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

Assume that $DB>DC$, then $\angle BCD>\angle CBD$. So $\alpha>\beta$. From the following picture
[image]

we see that $AE<AF$. Thus, in $\triangle AEF$ we have $x>y$. But $x+\alpha=y+\beta$ is a contradiction.

Comment: @N.S. Why does it not work any more? In the second picture, ray $CF$ and ray $CA$ lie in two sides of ray $CE$. Thus $E$ is always in between $A$ and $F$. We don't assume anything on $\angle EAC$.

Comment: @N.S. I concluded nothing about $CE$ and $CF$.

Comment: my mistake, +1.

Answer (score 0):

Draw two perpendicular lines from $CH_1$ to $DB$ and from $BH_2$ to $CD$.

For the sake of contradiction we assume $DB>DC$.

By area of $DBC$ we have $CH_1<BH_2$ hence area of triangle $S_{DEC}<S_{DFB}$ and $S_{AFC}<S_{AEB}$ which implies $AF<AE$ because $AB=AC$ and angle $FAC=EAB$.

Hence we have $BF<CE$ as well. Now ${DF\over sin(DBF)}={BF\over sin(D)} < {EC\over sin(D)} = {DE\over sin(DCE)}$.

This implies $sin(DBF)>sin(DCE)$

(1) When both $DBF$ and $DCE$ are less than $90$ degrees we arrive at a contradiction because angle $DBF>DEC$ implies $DBC>DCB$ and $DB<DC$.

(2) When $DBF$ is larger than $90$ degrees, then $DBC>90$ as well and $DB<DC$ contradiction.

(3) When $DCE$ is larger than $90$ degrees we have $DBF>180-DCE$ and $DBF+DCE>180$ contradiction.

(4) When both are larger than $90$ degrees $DCB+DBC>180$ contradiction.

Answer (score -2):

Given that DE=DF, a parallel line can be drawn through EF which is parallel to BC. as AB=AC angleABC=angleACB,THUS following that angleFEA=angleEFA WHICH implies EA=FA .THUS due to all of these angleDBF=angleDCE and thus DB=DC .

Comment: You can't deduce $EF\parallel BC$ just from $DE=DF$.

Comment: Who said that we are able to draw line passing through  $E$ and $F $, and parrallel to  $BC$ ?

Comment: COMMON man, can't you see that DE=DF, due to this EF IS PARALLEL TO BC .THINK!!

Comment: No, I can't see this. Could you explain this in greater detail?

Comment: SEE, from the given facts AB=AC forms an isosceles triangle and if EF IS NOT PARALLEL to BC then implies that DE IS NOT EQUAL TO DF.and also check the alternating angles formed due to the base triangle .that might give you some insight

Comment: @MohanR Sorry , but  I dont understand why  " if EF IS NOT PARALLEL to BC then implies that DE IS NOT EQUAL TO DF " !!!  and in your comment what is the use of " from the given facts AB=AC forms an isosceles triangle " ?

Comment: You are assuming what you are trying to prove.  Yes, ABC is an isosceles triangle but you haven't established any relation between ABC and point E and F which have nothing to do with the triangle.

Comment: Never mind that last sentence , just try to form the alternating angles due to the equal angles at the base of isosceles triangle and you will find the relation btw E AND F